# how to do confirmation in a form before submit

Tags: html, forms, confirm

I have this code

```
<form action="UMS_delete.php" method="post" onSubmit="return confirm("Are You Sure?");">
<td>
<input type="hidden" value="'.$row['username'].'" name="username">
<input type="submit" value="Delete">
</td>
</form>
```

I know it's very simple but it doesn't work and I don't know why

I have also tried the onclick event on the submit button

but it always go to the action page

can anybody please help?

Comment: Looking for [this](http://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/)?

Comment: Instead of `type="submit"` use `type="button"` with an onclick method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's the use of double quotes in the confirm.  It breaks the HTML syntax.

Do this instead:
onSubmit="return confirm('Are You Sure?');"

This should work, I've done this many many times.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
var el = document.getElementById('myCoolForm');
el.addEventListener('submit', function(){
return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this form?');
}, false);
```

Add ID to form for separate JavaScript

```
<form action="UMS_delete.php" method="post" id="myCoolForm" onSubmit="return confirm("Are You Sure?");">
<td>
<input type="hidden" value="'.$row['username'].'" name="username">
<input type="submit" value="Delete">
</td>
</form>
```

Or you can always use inline JS code like this:

```
<form action="adminprocess.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this form?');">
<input type="submit" name="completeYes" value="Complete Transaction" />
```

Comment: @David Pullar, The type is fine. I have forms that do that and work just fine!

Answer (score 0):

you just put by onclick function

```
> <input type="submit" name="completeYes" value="Complete Transaction" onclick="return confirm("Are You Sure?");"/>
```

or

```
 onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure?');"
```